# How to click on text located within the list of an html page which has no unique identifier using python selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, xpath

I'd like to select and click on the text 'Click Me Please' within this [html link](http://stackoverflowtest.site44.com/) using python selenium.

The challenge is that there is no unique identifier on the item and it's located within a list.

The specific html code looks like this:

```
<li class="tile no-tile-status both price-suggestion-high"> <div class="date"> <span class="day-number"> <!-- react-text: 496 -->Click Me Please<!-- /react-text --> </span> </div> <div class="price"><span> $529 </span></div> <div class="price-suggestion-highlight"></div> </li>
```

I've tried the following methods with no success:

Attempt 1

```
driver.get("http://stackoverflowtest.site44.com/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Click Me Please").click()
#>>Message: u'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Click Me Please"}\n  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)'
```

Attempt 2

```
driver.get("http://stackoverflowtest.site44.com/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("<!-- react-text: 496 -->Click Me Please<!-- /react-text -->").click()
#>>Message: u'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"<!-- react-text: 496 -->Click Me Please<!-- /react-text -->"}\n  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)'
```

Note: I also want to be able to click on the other dates in the list such as the following html elements:

```
<li class="tile no-tile-status both price-suggestion-high"> <div class="date"><span class="day-number"><!-- react-text: 511 -->18<!-- /react-text --></span></div> <div class="price"><span>$533</span></div> <div class="price-suggestion-highlight"></div> </li>

<li class="tile no-tile-status both price-suggestion-high"> <div class="date"><span class="day-number"><!-- react-text: 525 -->20<!-- /react-text --></span></div> <div class="price"><span>$569</span></div> <div class="price-suggestion-highlight"></div> </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I'd recommend using CSS selector as it's performance is better, but here you need to find it by it's text, so XPath will do the trick:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class='day-number' and text()='Click Me Please']')
```

Just a note: clicking it doesn't do anything... :/ so don't expect anything to happen...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [XPath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Click Me Please"]')
```

Comment: Since the item is in a list, I altered your suggestion by replacing the 'a' tag name with 'li', but this doesnt seem to work: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[text()="Click Me Please"]'). The 'a' tag isn't present on the other items on the list, so I can't use 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Dave's answer is mostly correct, except you'll probably have to replace the `//a`with `//li` since it's referenced this way.

OK, looking at it more closely, the issue is that the link text can change as it includes "react-text", etc.

I'd suggest using -

```
.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Click Me Please")
```